# Why is my api key not accepted by the Google Directions (Android) request?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Whenever I include my Google Play Services API key along with my request for Google Directions like in the code below:

```
    private String makeDirectionsURL(double originLat, double originLong, double destLat, double destLong)
{
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    //first part of url//
    url.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?");
    //start adding parameters//
    //origin coordinates
    url.append("origin="+originLat+","+originLong);
    //destiniation coordinates
    url.append("&destination=");
    url.append(destLat+","+destLong);
    //api key
    url.append("&key=");
    url.append(getResources().getString(R.string.google_api_key));
    //NOTE: for some reason, the request suceeds when leaving out the api key 

    return url.toString();

}
```

When I include the api key as a parameter in the request, the json response shows that my request has been denied. The response reads:

{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "routes" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}

Yet the same api key works for my google map view - and my api console registers the accesses for the map view quota limit. Even odder yet, when I leave out the key parameter in the Directions request I get a valid JSON response.

I have a feeling that I have to generate another different api key for just the Google Directions service - but I'm not sure how to. The documentation here:
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#api_key

Says to visit the console and activate the Directions API service - I did. 
Then it says my api key "will be available from the API Access page, in the Simple API Access section. Directions API applications use the Key for server apps." Now is where I'm confused - how can I use the key for server apps if I am accessing from a mobile device - I'm assuming this is for any webpages that wish to use the service - but what do I do for an android app. As I said, I already tried using my Simple API Access key for Android apps, which I know works, yet when I pass the same key to Google Directions - it mysteriously doesn't work...

Any help, vague guidance, or links to read up on would be really appreciated.

PS: If I can't figure this out - am I allowed to keep sending requests w/o a api key?

Comment: I'd also like to note that the error message indicates that the API key **is recognized as an API key** - its just not recognized as being linked to my application. I tested this by changing deleting part of my api key string resource and **the response that time changed to say it was not a valid api key.**

Comment: Response for this problem here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47799745/google-directions-returns-request-denied-when-called-from-android

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is because you are trying to pass a `server key` which is directly tied to your server's IP address, when you should be passing an `android app key`.

In your Google APIs console, navigate to **API's and Auth**. From here you can create a new public API key.

[image: Create Android Key]

When prompted, select **Android Application**
[image]

You will need to enter your device's **SHA1 Certificate Fingerprint**

This comes from the keystore used to sign the apk.  When running an app in debug, you will most likely be using your IDE's debugging keystore.  Google has a nice [write up](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#generatingdevkeys) on how to get this information.

*When releasing the app, you will need to sign it with your own key.  You will either need to edit your API key to the new keystore SHA1 fingerprint or create a new API key.*

Additionally, according to [Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#api_key), you should be using a key.

> All Directions API applications should use an API key. Including a key
>   in your request:
>
> - Allows you to monitor your application's API usage in the APIs
> - Console. Enables per-key instead of per-IP-address quota limits.
> - Ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary.

While I can't comment on how strictly they enforce this, I strongly encourage you to do so to avoid any issues down the road.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I was already using my android application key - the same one that I used to authenticate my MapView. I'll try creating another key for the with the same SHA1:package name combination and use that separately for my Google Directions requests. Maybe one needs a separate api key for each api service?  Edit:It didn't work...

Comment: I apologize, I misread a part of your post.  Using Google Cloud Messaging, I had run into an issue before where it would reject my key until I finally gave up and made a new one.

Comment: @bw15 did you ever figure out the problem? I'm running into the same issue (trying to use by API key that works with Maps v2).

Comment: @MikeCole Unfortunately no - I moved on and never got back to looking into it more - sorry!

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, the key is not to use your Android key. You have to make a Server key in the Google Developers Console (in the same place you made the Android key). That key can be used for several other Google APIs as well.

Comment: @MikeCole I've run into the same issue (Android key works for Masp, Places API, but not for Directions) and I'll give a try to creating Server key instead. But we have a problem here, don't we? In case with server key we are prompted to specify URL pattern of our web sites from which the requests are sent. If we use this key with Android, we are not able to specify any referrer restrictions. Is that a neccessary trade-off and does it pose a threat to our app's security?

Comment: It did work with server key. It's written here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#client-id that one should use server key. Still I don't get it if it's ok to use without referrer's restrictions

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina I haven't run into any issues so far with this. Glad the Server key did the trick for you.