# Google directions returns REQUEST_DENIED when called from Android

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am sending a HTTP request to Google Directions and I keep getting `REQUEST_DENIED` from my Android app. I already checked the SHA-1 that I had configured in the API key in Google console and also made sure that the directions API is enabled for my project. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the api key you are using from the android app is **unrestricted**. **Google Maps Directions does not support android restricted keys** yet, only IP addresses restrictions (which u can't do for android apps)

From documentation:

> Google Maps APIs are available via HTTP web services, for web browsers, and Android or iOS apps. APIs in any platform can use a generic (unrestricted) API key. You can optionally add a restriction (for example, IP addresses) to the API key. Once restricted, a key will only work on platforms that support that type of restriction.
>
> Tip:
> Before moving your app or website to production, you should secure your API key. **Keys for the Google Maps Directions API use the IP addresses (web servers, cron jobs, etc.) key restriction**